# Sitecore Package upload error

Tags: sitecore

I am trying to install a Sitecore package from dev to staging environment, i have used package designer to create this package, but when i try to upload this package on the staging site it results in the following error:

```
The File exists.<br>
```

I have also tried uploading the package created using the Sitecore Rocks plugin which also results in the same error.
I am installing the package using installation wizard and uploading the package and i am not overwriting the existing files.

Kindly, help!

Comment: Check the Sitecore logs.  You may find some useful information there.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs if the windows temp has more than 65K files. When we cleared those files the issue got resolved.

Comment: Yes, I faced with same issue and clearing temp folder solved it.

Comment: I made the mistake of going to `%TEMP%` instead of `c:\windows\temp`. `c:\windows\temp` had the 65k files and that's the one I needed to clear.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is package with the same name as your new package. Try to rename you package zip file and then upload.

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure you are installing in the right environment
2. make sure the file doesnt not already exists (you can look it under the packages folder)
3. restart app pool and try again. Maybe overwrite the installation file.

Comment: Tried everything u said thanks a lot. but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

there was a issue with sitecore on the staging environment(probably corrupted install). so we took a risk and installed it on live..! It works fine! Thank you all for the help. Much appreciated.